# "Get" route with query string and custom params

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5.13.

My goal is to create an endpoint like this:

```php
/api/items/{name}?kind={kind}
```

Where `kind` is optional parameter passed in by the query string.

My current routes in `api.php` looks like this:

```php
Route::get('items', 'DisplaynameController@show');
```

My current controller is like this:

```php
public function show(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->input('kind') {
        // TODO
    } else {
        return Item::where('name', '=', $request->input('name'))->firstOrFail();
    }
}
```

I

I am currently using `$request->input('name')` but this means I need to provide `?name=blah` in the query string. I am trying to make it part of the route.

May you please provide guidance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `$name` variable is a route param, not a query param, this means that you can pass it directly to the function as an argument.

So, if your route is like this:

```php
Route::get('items/{name}', 'DisplaynameController@show');
```

Your function should be like this:

```php
public function show(Request $request, $name) // <-- note function signature
{   //                                 ^^^^^
    if ($request->has('kind'))
    {
        // TODO
    }
    else
    {
        return Item::where('name', '=', $name)->firstOrFail(); // <-- using variable
    }   //                              ^^^^^
}
```

---

Another option is to get the variable as a [Dynamic Property](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#retrieving-input) like this:

```php
public function show(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->has('kind'))
    {
        // TODO
    }
    else
    {
        return Item::where('name', '=', $request->name)->firstOrFail();
    }   //                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Notice that we access the `name` value as a dynamic property of the `$request` object like this:

```php
$request->name
```

---

For more details, check the [Routing > Route parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters) and [Request > Retrieving input](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#retrieving-input) sections of the documentation.

Comment: Oh interesting, thank you for helping with the docs. The first challenge to learning something new is to learning how to navigate the docs. I really appreciate it. So it is not possible to get query string parmeters auto binded?

Comment: @Blagoh for query params not yet, but Laravel can bind route params to match them to models as you can see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#creating-form-requests).  All you need to do is type-hint the request on your controller method.

Comment: Thank you sir @HCK!

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-parameters) you should do:

```
public function show($name, Request $request)
```

Laravel will take care of the variable binding

Comment: Thank you sir. By any chance do you know a better way for me to do the `$request->input('kind')` check? Is this is the Laravel recommended way?